# How to programmatically access Safari's reading list from iOS

Tags: ios, safari

Is it possible to access Safari's "Reading List" programmatically from iOS?  I know it is possible to do it from a Mac as described here:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3238741?start=0&tstart=0

Thanks,
gb

Comment: Link in question is broken. :(

Comment: I just tried it and it works for me.

Comment: Weird, maybe something's wrong with my Apple ID.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

iOS 7 added an API to add items to the reading list:

```
#import <SafariServices/SafariServices.h>
 
SSReadingList *readList = [SSReadingList defaultReadingList];
NSError *error = nil;

BOOL status = [readList addReadingListItemWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlToAdd]
                                            title:titleToAdd
                                      previewText:previewText
                                            error:&error];
 
if (status) {
    NSLog(@"Added URL");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

As Ashok pointed out in the comments, it's not possible to retrieve items from the reading list.

Comment: I'll have to check it out!

Comment: This is only for adding, I think it's not possible to access the reading list, check the possible things here   
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SafariServices/Reference/SafariServicesFramework_Ref/

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. There is no API for accessing the reading list. Moreover, it doesn't help if you find out the plist file's location, because of the sandbox environment it can't be accessed.