# How to add an URL to Safari's reading list in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, safari, url-scheme

In my UIWebView I would like to add an option to add the current page to Safari's reading list.
I know this feature exists since GMail offers it when long-pressing a link, yet I can't find any info on what URL scheme to use.

Possible duplicate: [How to programmatically access Safari's reading list from iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529493/how-to-programmatically-access-safaris-reading-list-from-ios)

Comment: Also looking for a solution for this but haven't found anything yet. If I long press on my UIWebview links I get the option but can't figure out a way to make a custom button or UIActivity for that option

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically access Safari's reading list from iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529493/how-to-programmatically-access-safaris-reading-list-from-ios)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS 7 added an API to accomplish this:

```
#import <SafariServices/SafariServices.h>

SSReadingList * readList = [SSReadingList defaultReadingList];
NSError * error = [NSError new];

BOOL status =[readList addReadingListItemWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlToAdd] title:titleToAdd previewText:previewText error:&error];

if(status)
{
        NSLog(@"Added URL");

}
else    NSLog(@"Error");
```

Comment: Is it possible in latest iOS(9.2) versions?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the action sheet you're seeing in gmail is simply a built-in of UIWebView, inaccessible to developers.